# How to include PortAudio into a pyinstaller onefile build

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, portaudio

I am using sounddevice in my project running on Ubuntu - When I build a single file using pyinstaller it is failing with (The code works well when running the source python file):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Run_SD.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "Smart_Device.py", line 26, in init Smart_Device
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "sounddevice.py", line 71, in <module>
OSError: PortAudio library not found
[213] Failed to execute script Run_SD
```

Unfortunately I can't simply apt get install the required portaudio on the machine, so it needs to be included in the package.  I have tried adding in the lib using:

```
--add-binary libportaudio.so:.  --add-binary libportaudio.a:.
```

But this isn't working. I'm guessing I need to actually import the portaudio library into my python source - is that correct? Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you read `pyinstaller` documentation? There are informations how to resolve some problems.

Comment: maybe you should use `/full/path/to/libportaudio.so`

Comment: I updated with the full error message.
I don't need the full path to the libportaudio.so as It's right in the source directory (copied earlier), so it is being added in without a problem.

Comment: I only guess - maybe `pyinstaller` runs in different folder and it needs full path to find it. It is most common problem. Other idea - `pyinstaller` should create file `.spec` which you can use to add modules/libraries/resources and maybe you find in documentation how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by editing:

versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks/hook-sounddevice.py

```
elif is_linux:
    path = os.path.join(
        sfp[0], "_sounddevice_data", "portaudio-binaries", "libportaudio.so"
    )
```

versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sounddevice.py

```
    elif _platform.system() == 'Linux':
        _libname = 'libportaudio.so'
```

Then included the libportaudio.so in the pyinstaller build:

```
--add-binary _sounddevice_data/portaudio-binaries/libportaudio.so:./_sounddevice_data/portaudio-binaries/
```